Fréchet differentiability question
I have quite a difficult question regarding Fréchet and Gateaux differentiability. Suppose we have $T: L_2[0,1] \to L_2[0,1]$. $Tx(t) = \sin{x(t)}$. How to show that T is Gateaux differentiable everywhere on the interval, though not Fréchet differentiable. I think we need to somehow use that $L_2[0, 1]$ and $C[0, 1]$ are connected and then use the fact that $N_{\phi}: C[0, 1] \to C[0, 1]$, $N_{\phi}(x)(t) = \phi(t, x(t))$. And its derivative is just the Jacobi matrix of the mapping $\xi \to \phi(t, \xi)$. However I don't know how to get the contradiction that it doesn't work in this Lebesgue space.

see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164117/example-where-g%c3%a2teaux-differentiability-does-not-imply-fr%c3%a9chet-differentiability?rq=1
